# Emscripten: how do I detect webgl context version in runtime?

Tags: webgl, emscripten

I use GLFW3 and GLEW wrappers in Emscripten, so I don't call `emscripten_webgl_create_context` manually and don't set context's properties. The context version is determined only by JS code, which is out of my scope. In my C++ code I need to know whether we run in WebGL1 or WebGL2 context. Is there a document-independent way to do it? Something like:

```cpp
const auto ctx = emscripten_webgl_get_current_context();
emscripten_webgl_get_context_version(ctx);// Should return 1 or 2.
```

Comment: call [`glGetString`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glGetString.xhtml) with `GL_VERSION` in C++?

Comment: @gman it's hardware dependent. Too unreliable.

Comment: It's not hardware dependent in WebGL/emscripten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++

```
const char ES_VERSION_2_0[] = "OpenGL ES 2.0";
const char ES_VERSION_3_0[] = "OpenGL ES 3.0";

const char* version = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
if (strncmp(version, ES_VERSION_2_0, sizeof(ES_VERSION_2_0)) == 0) {
  // it's WebGL1
} else if (strncmp(version, ES_VERSION_3_0, sizeof(ES_VERSION_3_0)) == 0) {
  // it's WebGL2
} else {
  // it's something else
}
```

Version strings in WebGL have a required non-hardware dependent starting format. See [the spec for WebGL2](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/2.0/#3.7.2)

> VERSION:    Returns a version or release number of the form WebGL<space>2.0<optional><space><vendor-specific information></optional>.

and for [WebGL1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/#5.14.3)

> VERSION:   Returns a version or release number of the form WebGL<space>1.0<space><vendor-specific information>.

Emscripten also returns fixed strings. See the source

https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/ec764ace634f13bab5ae932912da53fe93ee1b69/src/library_gl.js#L923